# the point disappear in excel

Tags: vb.net, excel, datagridview

i am using this code to save DGV into excel file:

```
If ((DataGridView1.Columns.Count = 0) Or (DataGridView1.Rows.Count = 0)) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Creating dataset to export
    Dim dset As New DataSet
    'add table to dataset
    dset.Tables.Add()
    'add column to that table
    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
        dset.Tables(0).Columns.Add(DataGridView1.Columns(i).HeaderText)
    Next
    'add rows to the table
    Dim dr1 As DataRow
    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
        dr1 = dset.Tables(0).NewRow
        For j As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
            dr1(j) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value

        Next
        dset.Tables(0).Rows.Add(dr1)
    Next

    Dim excel As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim wBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Dim wSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet

    excel = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    wBook = excel.Workbooks.Add()
    wSheet = wBook.ActiveSheet()

    Dim dt As System.Data.DataTable = dset.Tables(0)
    Dim dc As System.Data.DataColumn
    Dim dr As System.Data.DataRow
    Dim colIndex As Integer = 0
    Dim rowIndex As Integer = 0

    For Each dc In dt.Columns
        colIndex = colIndex + 1
        excel.Cells(1, colIndex) = dc.ColumnName
    Next

    For Each dr In dt.Rows
        rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
        colIndex = 0
        For Each dc In dt.Columns
            colIndex = colIndex + 1
            excel.Cells(rowIndex + 1, colIndex) = dr(dc.ColumnName)

        Next
    Next

    wSheet.Columns.AutoFit()
    Dim strFileName As String = "D:\ss.xls"
    Dim blnFileOpen As Boolean = False
    Try
        Dim fileTemp As System.IO.FileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(strFileName)
        fileTemp.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        blnFileOpen = False
    End Try

    If System.IO.File.Exists(strFileName) Then
        System.IO.File.Delete(strFileName)
    End If

    wBook.SaveAs(strFileName)
    excel.Workbooks.Open(strFileName)
    excel.Visible = True
```

but when excel page show up, some number do not have the point, for exemple in datagridview X = 5.76546753435677 but in excel it will be like X = 576546753435677
can you help me plz.

Comment: What language is your code?  `For i As Integer = 0 To ...` is not valid VBA syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The decimal mark is different in your pieces of software, probably Excel and this VB (VB.NET?) environment. 
Excel by default is using the regional settings of windows for number formatting (decimal mark and thousands separator), but you can override it. At the same time, if the above code runs in a web page for example, it will use the locale settings for number formatting. I think the difference between the two must cause the issue.